# Page number font size in Lilypond

Tags: lilypond

Is it possible? How can I set the font size for the page numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The page number is printed by the paper variables `oddHeaderMarkup` and `evenHeaderMarkup`. If you look into `ly/titling-init.ly` you will find the default values

```
oddHeaderMarkup = \markup
\fill-line {
  ""
  \unless \on-first-page-of-part \fromproperty #'header:instrument
  \if \should-print-page-number \fromproperty #'page:page-number-string
}

%% evenHeaderMarkup would inherit the value of
%% oddHeaderMarkup if it were not defined here
evenHeaderMarkup = \markup
\fill-line {
  \if \should-print-page-number \fromproperty #'page:page-number-string
  \unless \on-first-page-of-part \fromproperty #'header:instrument
  ""
}
```

As you see there is no hook to format the page number. So you’ll need to adjust this header as you deem fit:

```
\paper {
  oddHeaderMarkup = \markup
  \fill-line {
    ""
    \unless \on-first-page-of-part \fromproperty #'header:instrument
    \if \should-print-page-number \larger \fromproperty #'page:page-number-string
  }

  evenHeaderMarkup = \markup
  \fill-line {
    \if \should-print-page-number \larger \fromproperty #'page:page-number-string
    \unless \on-first-page-of-part \fromproperty #'header:instrument
    ""
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see where I can set the font size

Comment: `\if \should-print-page-number \larger \fromproperty #'page:page-number-string` the `\larger` increases fontsize by one magstep. Alternatively you can do `\fontsize #number` or `\abs-fontsize #number`.

Comment: So I added `oddHeaderMarkup = \markup
  \fill-line {
    ""
    \unless \on-first-page-of-part \fromproperty #'header:instrument
    \if \should-print-page-number \abs-fontsize #10 \fromproperty #'page:page-number-string
  }

  evenHeaderMarkup = \markup
  \fill-line {
    \if \should-print-page-number \abs-fontsize #10 \fromproperty #'page:page-number-string
    \unless \on-first-page-of-part \fromproperty #'header:instrument
    ""
  }` to the `\paper` part of my ly file, and the result is not what it should be. Should it be added to the titling-init.ly file?

Comment: @Student No. `titling-init.ly` is a Lilypond default file, editing it will mean you’ll need to maintain this change over future Lilypond versions. But what to you mean by "the result is not what it should be"? This should change the font size for odd page numbers to be slightly smaller (the default is 11).